# cProfile for non terminating python program

Tags: python, profiling, infinite-loop, cprofile, faulthandler

I have a non terminating python program that I debug with

```
import faulthandler
faulthandler.dump_traceback_later(480,exit=True)
call_very_complicated_python_code()
```

I want to profile it to gain better understanding which parts are stuck:

```
$ python -m cProfile -o program.prof my_program.py my_input.txt
```

- Does `faulhandler` mechanism interfere with the profiling?
- `program.prof` is **not** always generated.
- Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used `faulthandler`, but sounds like the wrong tool for the job anyway. If you code never ends or errors, where is the traceback coming from?

Profiling is used to measure the speed of your code. If you want to understand the code, I'd suggest debugging it with something like pdb.

Add `import pdb` up the top of your module(s).

In areas you'd like to stop and inspect add: `pdb.set_trace()`

Perhaps you have some recursion or loop which is never competed?